# What could be used to create oscillations of sine waves with 200 Amps peak at 50 MHz?

Tags: oscillator, high-current

And I have no idea how would that much AC affect the nearby environment.

Comment: To be fair, that sounds like a very ambitious task, and the fact that you're not even listing the typical oscillator architectures here with your thoughts why they would not or would work is an indication that you probably won't be able to pull this off without learning a lot of electronics on the way. So maybe start with something easier?

Comment: also, 200A ?! seriously, either you have access to knowledge and infrastructure and a travelling wave tube, or to superconductive circuitry. Both assumptions don't align the least with the naivety you ask these questions.

Comment: Although you might create a 200A pk current oscillation with "classical" methods such as used in high-power broadcast transmissions, the voltages necessary to create such a current in any real, non-superconducting material will be extremely high, and the circuit would, for a lot of reasons, be extremely dangerous to you, who seems to be an absolute electronics beginner.

Comment: The question is about meaningless as stated. What power level? What voltage? What application? What environment? What acceptable cost. | As the question stands an answer such as 'buy or build or use a 200 kW 50 MHz transmitter'  is as good as any other.

Comment: You get one of my VERY rare downvotes - you can and must do better than that. NOBODY in any context can answer that question efficiently with the supplied information. You should try not to waste people's time by not trying harder to provide as much information as reasonably possible.

Comment: A klystron might do it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond go for it!

Comment: @Andyaka wait, are you handing out free linear beam resonant devices? Where do I sign up?

Comment: @BrianDrummond to be fair, TWTs and Klystrons are typically used for significantly higher freqs than 50 MHz for size reasons, and because below, "classical" amplifiers still work at larger power levels, AFAIK. Nice thing about beam-based devices of course is that OP's 200A aren't media-bound, ie. you don't melt any conductors. However, the high-energy microwave folks at KIT used to have slides with the holes a couple-GHz beam within a klystron misaligned by 0.2° shoots into solid metal... so, um... no, let's at least not hand one of these devices to OP.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are correct Sir! My 1983 databook (old enough to say Mullard on the cover) lists klystrons for 470MHz and upwards. There may possibly be lower frequency ones from the 1950s or 60s for VHF television transmitter applications, but my databook shelf is a bit thin for that era...

Comment: It's obnoxious to use the title to ask a question.  In any case, this is too broad, gives no background on the real problem, and is generally thumbing your nose at us.  Closing this mess.

Comment: This will show you the kind of equipment you need to handle that kind of power: https://youtu.be/mR_wJkxKSXU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Optimistic first thought...

An extremely high Q parallel resonant circuit sounds, to me, like your best option. If it has a Q factor of 141 you can tickle the tuned circuit with a sinewave of 1 amp sourced from a highly compliant current source and, if you took great care in the design of the inductor, you would get a result.

So how practical is this idea?

To get 200 amps peak (or 141 ARMS) into an inductor requires a decent sized voltage so, let's assume that the inductor voltage is 141 V. So clearly, the reactance of the inductor is 1 at 50 MHz. This means it has an inductance of 1/(2 pi 50e6) = 3.18 nH and right now this is not sounding too optimistic because that's equivalent to a piece of wire about 6mm long.

So the inductance, for practical purposes has to be at least ten times this value and when 141 ARMS is flowing the voltage across it will be 1410 VRMS.

Pessimistic final thought...

These are really big problems and although I've built many high current tuned circuits I feel right now that this would be beyond my skillset. Given that you are asking the question, you probably don't appreciate the intricasies in this so, I'm going to have to say that if you worked hard at it for a year you wouldn't get to within 10% of your goal. Sorry!

Comment: /me is compelled to upvote :) no, really, this is both insightful for OP and reflective. I know I'd have no idea how to actually pull this off, and I'd probably try to buy used military/broadcast equipment for the high power amps, and still be at a loss on how to stably operate this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. I feel ashamed of asking such simple questions but I can hardly grasp anything beyond RLC circuits and semiconductor basics. I've been trying hard for a week to understand the Hartley and Colpitts oscillators and their variations.

Comment: I know this question was closed but you can still formally accept the answer or raise another comment should you need clarification on something.

Comment: @Xynon I draw your attention to the comment above.

Comment: I feel terrible about asking such a stupid question when I knew very little about oscillator circuits and yet you were indulgent. I can't re-write the question as the comments would be unrelated. At least, I learned not be hasty to ask everything without proper research first.

Comment: We are all learning!